# I am trying to embed a dropdown list into the navigation bar for this website i am creating. Can anyone help me?

Tags: html, css

I have tried embedding more <li> elements and have been modifying the css as I went along but nothing seems to work.

I modified the css as i went along with the hopes of getting 'specialists' to reveal the dropdown items when the cursor hovered with some sort of smooth animation that would be perfect for a professional website

```
/* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Show the dropdown content when hovering over the dropdown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Our Story</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Specialists</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
              <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">DBS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: Your code _basically_ works (https://jsfiddle.net/u5xo9dtL/) - but you won't get any sort of "animation", when you just toggle the `display` property value.

Comment: i want to embed an animation into the dropdown list so that when people use it they can access the desired page. I have attempted it above but cannot seem to get a dropdown arrow to dispaly

Answer (score 0):

Display property in CSS is not animatable. Try using properties like, max-height, transform, opacity, etc.

```css
/* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown content */
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in;
  transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Show the dropdown content when hovering over the dropdown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Our Story</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Specialists</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[Read more about CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#which_css_properties_can_be_transitioned)